# cmake: Target-specific preprocessor definitions for CUDA targets seems not to work

Tags: cmake, cuda

I'm using cmake 2.8.1 on Mac OSX 10.6 with CUDA 3.0.

So I added a CUDA target which needs BLOCK_SIZE set to some number in order to compile.

```
cuda_add_executable(SimpleTestsCUDA
                    SimpleTests.cu
                    BlockMatrix.cpp 
                    Matrix.cpp
)

set_target_properties(SimpleTestsCUDA PROPERTIES COMPILE_FLAGS -DBLOCK_SIZE=3)
```

When running `make VERBOSE=1` I noticed that `nvcc` is invoked w/o `-DBLOCK_SIZE=3`, which results in an error, because `BLOCK_SIZE` is used in the code, but defined nowhere. Now I used the same definition for a CPU target (using `add_executable(...)`) and there it worked.

So now the questions: How do I figure out what `cmake` does with the `set_target_properties` line if it points to a CUDA target? Googling around didn't help so far and a workaround would be cool..

Comment: Could anybody try this on Linux or Windows? I just have my MB pro here atm..

Comment: Doesn't work on Windows either.

Answer (score 4):

I think the best way to do this is by adding "OPTIONS -DBLOCK_SIZE=3" to cuda_add_executable. So your line would look like this:

```
cuda_add_executable(SimpleTestsCUDA
                SimpleTests.cu
                BlockMatrix.cpp 
                Matrix.cpp
                OPTIONS -DBLOCK_SIZE=3
)
```

Or you can set it before cuda_add_executable:

```
SET(CUDA_NVCC_FLAGS -DBLOCK_SIZE=3)
```

Comment: thank you, seems to work for now. Maybe I should report this as a bug?

Comment: SET(CUDA_NVCC_FLAGS -DBLOCK_SIZE=3) This is then the same for all targets, you cannot reset it using set; it will take the latest for all targets.

OPTIONS -DBLOCK_SIZE=3 seems to work with cuda targets but not with normal ones..

I think I get a headache.. :(

Comment: OPTIONS is only available with cuda_add_executable, for add_executable you should probably use set_target_properties.

Answer (score 0):

The only workaround I found so far is using remove_definitions:

```
remove_definitions(-DBLOCK_SIZE=3)
add_definitions(-DBLOCK_SIZE=32)
```

Doing this before a target seems to help.